# Laravel display image uploaded in view from database

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, database

I want to display images uploaded in view file to the database using laravel...the image are not loaded...

below is my view file where i want to display my image

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        @foreach($infor as $inform)
        <div class="card mb-3">
  <img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/'.$inform->imogi) }}" style="max-width:20%;" alt="Wild Landscape"/>
  <div class="card-body">
  <div style="text-align: right;">
        <small style="color:#3490dc;">{{$inform->organazation}}</small> <small><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ $inform->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}</small>
    </div>
    <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$inform->name}}</h5>
    <!--LIVEWIRE online status-->
    <div wire:key="UNIQUE_ID">
    @if($inform->isOnline())
        <small style="color:#3490dc;">  operative </small>                                    
    @else
        <small style="color:#3490dc;"> detached</small>
    @endif
    </div>

    <small><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$inform->location}}</small>
    <hr/>
  <h6 class="card-title"><b>{{$inform->title}}</b></h6>
        <p class="card-text">
        {{$inform->message}}
        </p>
        <small><small style="color:#3490dc;"><u><b>Qualifications:</b></u></small> {{$inform->qualifications}}</small>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
        <small><i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$inform->contact}}</small>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

below is my upload controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function fileUpload()
    {
        return view('fileUpload');
    }
    //
    public function fileUploadPost(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv|max:2048',
        ]);
  
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();  
   
        $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);
   
        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload file.')
            ->with('file',$fileName);
   
    }
}
```

Here is my storage path in filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

And below is the blade view where the image is being uploaded

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <form action="message" method="POST">
         @csrf
         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:24px"></i> Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="name" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-building-o" style="font-size:24px"></i> Organazation</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="organazation">
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('organazation'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Type your organazation or state whether individual</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:24px"></i> Location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="location">
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('location'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Type your location</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:24px"></i> Job title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="title">
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('title'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Enter the title for the job</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:24px"></i> Job description</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('message'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Describe the type of job being offered</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:24px"></i> Qualifications</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="qualifications">
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('qualifications'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Enter the qualifications and experience required</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:24px"></i> Contacts</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="contact">
    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('contact'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
    <small>Enter phone contacts</small>
  </div>
  <form action="{{ route('file.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
  
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imogi">
                </div>
            </div>
            <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('imogi'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>
            <small>Select business logo if any or implicating image</small>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

I can display any image in my view except the one i uploaded...i dont know where am getting this wrong...i will appreciate any kind of help

Thank You!

Comment: Are the images stored successfully in the `uploads` folder?

Comment: how do you upload the file? I do not see neither an html nor an ajax form

Comment: The image are stored becouse i can access them on my admin panel...but don`t know if they are stored in a proper way becouse only the name of the image are displayed in table...

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
{{ URL::asset('storage/uploads/'.$inform->imogi) }}
```